# Getting a model works fine but when I also try to eager load a model, the query returns an empty array in Sequelize.js

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following Model query:

```
let response = await Model.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        name: 'Q7'
    }
})
```

Which works fine and returns 1 record which is what I expect.

When I try this:

```
let response = await Model.findAll({
    where: {
        name: 'Q7'
    },
    include: {
        model: Part
    }
})
```

I still get the model and the associated parts to that model.

The problem happens when I also try to include a `where` to my eager loading. If the model has parts that have a `categoryId` of 1, I do get returned 1 record that also contains the parts, however, if the model doesn't have any parts with that categoryId, the whole returned model is just an empty array.

I expected that if there weren't any parts with that categoryId, I'd just get the model and the parts property would be an empty array or something, but instead, the whole model becomes an empty array.

```
let response = await Model.findAll({
    where: {
        name: 'Q7'
    },
    include: {
        model: Part,
        where: {
            categoryId: '1'
        }
    }
})
```